# Identify this commercial(?) jet approaching Songshan airport in Taipei with what looks like very long inner flaps

Tags: aircraft-identification

Taken from a bus window on a highway leaving Taipei going west and south, these photos show what I assume is a commercial jet on roughly northeast(?) approach to Taipei's [Songshan Airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Songshan_Airport) July 24, 2023 at 16:45 UTC+08 (local time).

Twin engines at the rear just in front of the tail, and sort-of-delta-ish-wings rather than skinny ones, but maybe it's just very long inner flaps compared to what I'm used to seeing? If so, maybe a short description of why the wings + flaps seem to look different than what a long time passenger might think flaps normally look like would be helpful.

Photos taken by cell phone through a tinted bus window pointing very high (almost straight up) by the third and closest one.

[image: what's this plane?]

[image: what's this plane?] [image: what's this plane?] [image: what's this plane?] click for full size

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It could be a Bombardier Global 7500 by a quick search. I can't find any good pictures from under but they look kinda similar, and depending on the livery of the plane you saw, could've operated in Taiwan as a private jet

[image: G700 blueprints]

Comment: Wing shape a better match IMO than an MD-80 in the other answer. Also the winglets, almost visible in the source image.

Comment: This was just a quick search, I'm not a civilian aviation kind of guy. That's why I used an F/A-18 on my profile picture rather than, say, a 777

Comment: The pointy nose is also a better match. This could very well be it.

Comment: I agree.  It's probably a Bombardier Global 7500.

Comment: The gear placement is very similar too, although I couldn't find an image for the underside

Comment: looks very much like it. swept back winglets are kind of noticeable on OP's picture

Comment: It seems's you've nailed it, thank you for your speedy answer!

Answer (score 16):

It was a Bombardier Global 7500 (all credits should go to Mateo, he was the [first to identify the aircraft type correctly](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/100242/19)). This aircraft, registration 9H-VID was operating for VistaJet, flight VJT750 from Tokyo  (HND) to Taipei (TSA).

[image: Photo of the aircraft]
<sub>source: [Jetphotos](https://www.jetphotos.com/photo/10945846), copyright [atc1110](https://www.jetphotos.com/photographer/241767)</sub>

A screenshot from the Flight Radar 24 replay, showing the flight ID is below:

[image: Flight radar 24 screenshot showing the aircraft over Taipei]

[image]

Comment: Nice - traveling east out of Taipei on [Freeway 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Freeway_1) even explains why I saw it high out the left side window of my "luxury" bus, and that [Bombardier marketing focused on ultra-high-net-worth individuals and the Global 7500 is the largest, longest range, roomiest and most luxurious purpose-built business aircraft yet built](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bombardier_Global_7500#Global_7500_2) explains why it's unfamiliar to me :-)

Comment: @uhoh apparently ultra-high-net-worth individuals like the smell of old cigarettes and of dogs
https://aviapages.com/aircraft/9h-vid/ 
(yes, I am sure they circulate ozone through the cabin after each use to deeply clean it, but still ... )